# Extension of subharmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u$ be a positive subharmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq2$) except at a finite number of points. Is it possible to extend $u$ to a positive subharmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Maybe that should be "extend to a nonnegative subharmonic function"?

Comment: Under some condition (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is locally bounded above at these points, yes. It can be extended and the extension is the upper semi continuous regularization of the function.